# OOP, Interfaces, Objects and Casting

Tags: java, oop

I'm looking at some past exam papers for OOP and I would appreciate any help with understanding the following code. The question is, given this first block of code and that Sandwich implements Edible, which of the following statements are legal?

```
Sandwich sub = new Sandwich();
Rectangle cerealBox = new Rectangle(20,30,20,10);
Edible e = null;

e = sub;
sub = e;
sub = (Sandwich) e;
sub = (Sandwich) cerealBox;
e = cerealBox;
e = (Edible) cerealBox;
e = (Rectangle) cerealBox;
e = (Rectangle) null;
e = (Edible) sub;
cerealBox = (Rectangle) new Object();
```

My current understanding is that the first statement is true because a sub has the required elements to make up an edible Object, hence it does not work the other way round for the second statement. And with the third statement casting does allow this to work. But the fourth doesn't because cerealBox doesn't apply to Sandwich. Then the last two do work because of the casting. But apparently the 6th one works?

Sorry about my terrible explanation of what I know, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I remember this question from my books actually.

Your question was somewhat unclear, but I interpret that you're asking why the 6th statement is legal.  Because e must be set to another instance of Edible, casting the cerealBox to Edible is legal by the compiler, but you will still encounter a ClassCastException at runtime because Rectangle is not an instance of Edible.

Comment: In general, it’s important to clarify what is meant by “legal”. There is potentially a difference between failure at compile time, and failure at runtime. Would the latter be considered “legal”, since it compiles?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inheritance and interface implementation in Java are said to represent an “is-a” relationship. That is, if `Boy` inherits from `Person`, then `Boy` is-a `Person`. Consequently, it can be treated *as if it were* a `Person` (because it is). This in particular implies that it can be assigned to an instance of type `Person`.

Armed with this, we can decide that

1. `e = sub` compiles and runs fine. **[OK]**
2. `sub = e`, on the other hand, doesn’t compile: an is-a relationship cannot be reversed. **[!]**
3. `sub = (Sandwich) e` *forces* the above to compile through an explicit cast. Furthermore, since `e` at that point *does* contain a sandwich (from assignment 1), this cast also succeeds at runtime. **[OK]**
4. `sub = (Sandwich) cerealBox` – since there is no meaningful conversion from `Rectangle` to `Sandwich`, this fails to compile. **[!]**
5. `e = cerealBox` – Same here, for much the same reason. **[!]**
6. `e = (Edible) cerealBox` Here, the Java compiler capitulates: it allows the cast, even though we (the programmers) know that it can’t succeed since the object contained in `cerealBox` doesn’t implement `Edible` – but the compiler can’t know this: conceivably, the object contained in it could be derived from `Rectangle` (and hence assignable to `cerealBox`), and *also* implement `Edible`.

   So the compiler acquiesces. But at runtime, you’ll get a `ClassCastException`.

   Note how this statement differs from 4: there, the compiler knew that `cerealBox` couldn’t contain a `Sandwich`. But it *could* contain something `Edible`. Why? Because Java is single-inheritance (and `Rectangle` doesn’t inherit from `Sandwich`), but allows extending from multiple interfaces. **[C]**
7. `e = (Rectangle) cerealBox` fails, since the cast is actually completely meaningless (`cerealBox` is already of type `Rectangle`) and the remaining statement is equivalent to 5. **[!]**
8. `e = (Rectangle) null` fails, even though `null` *could* be assignable to an `Edible` object. But the cast makes this invalid for the same reason as 5 is invalid. **[!]**
9. `e = (Edible) sub` is valid, and equivalent to 1. The cast however is completely redundant, since Java performs casts upwards in the inheritance hierarchy implicitly. **[OK]**
10. `cerealBox = (Rectangle) new Object()` compiles, and crashes at runtime. The reason is similar to 6: `Object` is a base class of `Rectangle`; hence, an object *could* contain a `Rectangle` instance, which would make this statement succeed (see 3 for an example of that).

    True, the compiler is kind of stupid – it *could* see that the object being cast – `new Object()` – in no way could be a `Rectangle`. But the compiler doesn’t do this analysis, since it’s impossible in the general case. **[C]**

Key: [OK] = compiles, runs error-free. [C] = compiles, crashes. [!] = doesn’t compile.

As you can see, the question which statements are “legal” doesn’t quite cut it: some of these statements compile, but yield an exception at runtime. Are they legal?

Answer (score 1):

The 6th wouldn't work. Rectangle does not implement Edible, and as such cannot be casted to it.

Edit: See Vulcan's comment for why it is allowed by the IDE. You will receive a runtime error.